# Light won't turn on with new bulb

Tags: lighting

I am trying to replace a wall light (3 way switch that controls 2 lights simultaneously, shouldn't matter but just in case) with a new light bulb. Note the existing light is operational, so I know the circuit/switch/socket all works.

After replacing one light bulb, it just won't turn on (the other old bulb,remember there are two bulbs, still works). I tried the bulb on another table lamp and confirmed that the bulb itself is also operational. If I switch back the old bulb, it is operational again.

The bulb I am replacing is of a different shape, but they are using the same socket (E26). And the new one can fit in the socket, just little tighter. I did feel like I am screwing all the way down.

Now what could be the causes? Is there other spec of the light bulb that I need to match (other than socket) in order to make it work?

Comment: It is probably not making good contact with the socket parts that complete the electrical connection, I have seen this same issue, due to slight variation in bulb manufacture combined with old worn-out socket. Try smearing a bit of dielectric grease on the threads and bottom tip of the base of the new bulb, it might be that it just isn't screwing in far enough to touch the contact in the bottom of the socket.

Comment: If it's not the socket, perhaps it's something else?  Is either switch a dimmer?  Is the new bulb LED?  Troubleshooting 101 here...  hope you figure it out!

Comment: You can clean the socket with a corner of terrycloth and WD40, makes a lot of "chalky" old sockets operate smoothly. Sometimes it also helps, depending on the socket, if you can slightly bend up the little tab at the bottom of the socket to mate better with the tip of the bulb. Sometimes it's a nub instead of a flap, and if so, leave that alone besides cleaning. Lastly, a pencil eraser can clean tarnished brass contacts, which sometimes helps. If none of that works, replace the socket, they are cheap-ish.